# I can't get a float in python division

Tags: python, python-2.7, floating-point, integer, division

I was coding and I had this problem where I devide 5 / 2 and still get 2, not 2.5, and i get integers only. I don't know if it's a glitch, different python files give you either 2 or 2.5.
I need help!

```
print(5 / 2)
>>>2
```

what's supposed to happen:

```
print(5 / 2)
>>>2.5
```

It even happens when I do:

```
print(float(5 / 2))
>>>2
```

see? Still can't be a float as it's supposed to be!

Comment: You're using Python 2.  In Python 3, the result will be float.  To get the same effect in Python 2, use `float(5) / 2` (or just `5.0 / 2`).

Comment: @TomKarzes Or use `from __future__ import division`, if you are absolutely stuck in Python 2.

Comment: @chepner Interesting, I didn't know about `__future__`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably using an old Python version (previous to Python 3.x), that performs *integer* division by default. Try this:

```
5.0 / 2.0
=> 2.5
```

Or this:

```
from __future__ import division
5 / 2
=> 2.5
```

But as the comments mention, it'd be better if you upgraded to Python 3.x, the 2.x version was deprecated.

Comment: Thanks bro! It worked! The reason is, in fact, old version of python!

Comment: @CasualProgrammer If possible, you should switch to Python 3. Python 2 has reached end-of-life status, and is no longer maintained.

Comment: @chepner ok bro! I'm switching to python!